# How to export Root Certificates (Fiddler)

Tags: fiddler

I use Fiddler dll to install Fiddler certificates:

```
   public static bool InstallCertificate()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(certmakerBcCert))
        {
            FiddlerApplication.Prefs.SetStringPref("fiddler.certmaker.bc.key", certmakerBcKey);
            FiddlerApplication.Prefs.SetStringPref("fiddler.certmaker.bc.cert", certmakerBcCert);
        }

        if (!CertMaker.rootCertExists())
        {
            //CLog.writeNoLogInDB("Creating SSL certificate");
            if (!CertMaker.createRootCert())
                return false;

            if (!CertMaker.trustRootCert())
                return false;

            certmakerBcCert = FiddlerApplication.Prefs.GetStringPref("fiddler.certmaker.bc.cert", null);
            certmakerBcKey = FiddlerApplication.Prefs.GetStringPref("fiddler.certmaker.bc.key", null);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

I would need to export the RootCertificate file that is created through code. Is there a method to do so?

Answer (score 1):

(I know this is old, but incase you haven't found the answer or someone else is searching)

Based on your code it looks like your using the BouncyCastle certificate maker, so you can do this to export the root certficiate:

```
FiddlerApplication.Prefs.SetBoolPref("fiddler.certmaker.bc.EmitRootCertFile", true)
```

This will dump a "FiddlerBCRoot.pfx" on your desktop with an empty password